# link_to acting strangely in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

All my link_to's in my views seem to return the link text, but also the ink address in brackets. Why is this?

E.g

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url %>
```

and renders in the view

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/">Home (http://localhost:3000/) </a>
```

Comment: have you overridden the default behaviour in a module or helper possibly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your stylesheets.  For example, I know plenty of print media css does that for the benefit of those who can't "click" their paper.

Comment: Thanks dude, just started using Blueprint CSS framework, adn removing the print.css file solved this! :)